# Multi type populated data based on template parameters not arguements

Tags: c++, templates, templating

I'm trying to develop a basic ECS and I'm currently working on views
So far I have

```
//Grabs a ECSView (underlying vector of tuples) of components in the scene of Type T
ECSView<ComponentType> view  a = m_Scene.View<ComponentType>();
//usage example TransformComponent
ECSView<TransformComponent> transformView = m_ECSEntityRegistry.View<TransformComponent>();
```

How can I extend this functionality to take in multiple types in the template. I.E return Components in the tuple (both being attached to an entity), I can't figure out how to collect the data. I can setup the ECSView and it works but I don't know to iterate over the types of the template is this possible?

```
//For example
ECSView<TransformComponent, MeshRenderer> transformView = m_ECSEntityRegistry.View<TransformComponent, MeshRenderer>();
```

This is my code

```
template<typename ...Types>
        ECSView<Types...> View()
        {

            //works
            ECSView<Types...> view;

            //FOREACH TYPE IN TYPES
            //collect the data and add to the view

            
            //when done
            //the underlying vec of tuples would be
            [0] -> std::tuple<TransformComponent, MeshRenderer>
            [1] -> std::tuple<TransformComponent, MeshRenderer>
            ....
            return view;
        }
```

My ECSView for reference

```
template<class... Types>
    class ECSView
    {
    public:

        //*******

        std::vector< std::tuple<Types*...>> sets;


        //*******
    };
```